# Поясните, пожалуйста, почему GeoObjects undefined

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Версия 2.1

```
// добавляем так
BaseGeoObjectsArrayObj[0] = new ymaps.GeoObject(); // type: "Point"
BaseGeoObjectsArrayObj[1] = new ymaps.GeoObject(); // type: "Point"
....

var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({});
clusterer.add(BaseGeoObjectsArrayObj);
map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
```

Пытаюсь по клику по ссылке достучатся до GeoObjects

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "a[ViewForMapMi]", function(event){
                  console.log(map); // object
                  console.log(map.GeoObjects); // undefined 
                  event.preventDefault();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено не GeoObjects а geoObjects (с маленькой буквы, эх)